# Huge White Space At Bottom Of Page

Tags: css, html

I've obviously screwed up somewhere with the height in my webpage. I'm getting a massive amount of white space at the bottom of the page, way after the content. I can't find the specific problem, I've tried many different things. I thought it was time for someone else to take a look.

Here's the url:

Thanks!

Comment: remove your img tag inside your form with the `width: 110%;` and height: `150%;` or you can use this `width: 100%; height: auto;` in your img tag inside of the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is the issue:

```
img {
  width: 110%;
  height: 150%;
}
```

Which is causing this image to enlarge greatly:

```
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
```

For images, I tend to use the following:

```
img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: How do I fix that? Because I need the `img {
  width: 110%;
  height: 150%;
}`

Comment: If you set that, it's going to be applied to all images. If there are only certain images you need that applied to, create a class and apply that width and height to that class only.

Comment: Thanks, the `height: auto;` fixed everything!

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere on your page, you have this CSS:

```
img {
    width: 110%;
    height: 150%;
}
```

This is making a 1x1 image from PayPal form extremely big, and causing that big space. You should edit that code and make it apply only to the images you want, and not every image in your website.